# Angular 2 - Check If Any Default Values Have Changed

Tags: javascript, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am extremely new to `Angular 2` and am struggling to find a way to check if any value in my `md-input`'s have changed.

**HTML**

```
<md-card>
    <h3>Contact details</h3>
        <md-input-container class="containerRightMargin">
            <input mdInput placeholder="Telephone number" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.contact.telephoneNumber">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Email address" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.contact.email">
        </md-input-container>
        <div>
            <h3 class="headingWithButtonBeside">Address details</h3>
            <button *ngIf="!this.personalDetailsDisable" class="floatingButtonBesideHeading" md-button color="accent" title="Click to find your new address using your new postcode.">Use postcode lookup</button>
        </div>
        <md-input-container class="containerRightMargin">
            <input mdInput placeholder="Flat name" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.flatName">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Flat number" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.flatNumber">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="containerRightMargin">
            <input mdInput placeholder="House name" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.houseName">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="House number" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.houseNumber">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="containerRightMargin">
            <input mdInput placeholder="Street" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.street">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="District" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.district">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="containerRightMargin">
            <input mdInput placeholder="City" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.city">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="County" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.county">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="containerRightMargin">
            <input mdInput placeholder="Country" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.country">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Postcode" [disabled]="this.personalDetailsDisable" [(ngModel)]="accountService.client?.address.postCode">
        </md-input-container>
</md-card>
```

I have no idea how to check i can check all fields in one.  Reason for this is that unless any field value changes from the default value that is returned from my service, then i want a 'Save' button to display other wise i don't want the save button to be displayed.

I know this has to be done in my component and i have seen examples of `SimpleChange` etc but i cant get it work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could share your component source code we could see more. But so far it should be done like this. [Link to Angular docs.](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  prop: number;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```